# Print rows which do not match a pattern more than once, in a column of concatenated strings

Tags: awk

I would like to get a new file only with the rows that do not match a specific pattern more than once, in second column. That column is composed by different strings joined by `;`; so the idea is to get those rows where more than one of those strings are different from PASS.

```
ID1 PASS;mq;bq
ID2 bq
ID3 PASS
ID4 mq;hj;cigar
ID5 mq;PASS;PASS;PASS
ID6 bq;hj;PASS;PASS
```

I was trying something like this:

```
awk '! /PASS/ {print $1,$2}' myfile.tsv
```

But, actually I also want to print rows containing PASS, if they contain two other elements different from this pattern (in my real file, some rows present more than 15 strings in column 2). In addition, I am not sure how to indicate the "more than once" command. My expected output is this:

```
ID1 PASS;mq;bq
ID4 mq;hj;cigar
ID6 bq;hj;PASS;PASS
```

Do you know how can I achieve it?

Comment: Why is `ID5 mq;PASS;PASS;PASS` not printed in output?

Comment: @anubhava because a pattern different from PASS is not occurring more than once (just mq once)

Comment: Please don't just use the word `pattern` to describe what you want to match in the context of pattern matching as it's highly ambiguous. Assuming `PASS` in your question is a placeholder for some other string in your real data - is `PASS` intended to be treated as a string or a regexp? If it's a string, is it guaranteed to never contain regexp metachars like `.` or `*`? Can it contain `;`s or spaces? The right answer will all depend on what `PASS` is intended to be treated as and whichcharacters it can contain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk '
!/ PASS;|;PASS;|;PASS$/ && num=split($2,arr,";")>=2{ print; next }
{
  count=0
  num=split($2,arr,";")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    if(arr[i]!="PASS"){ count++ }
  }
  if(count>=2){ print; next }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this `awk`:

```bash
awk '{
   s = $2
   gsub(/^PASS|;(PASS)?/, ";", s)
   gsub(/^;+|;+$/, "", s)
}
split(s, a, /;+/) > 1' file

ID1 PASS;mq;bq
ID4 mq;hj;cigar
ID6 bq;hj;PASS;PASS
```

Comment: Nice! I think the first `gsub()` could use just `/PASS/` for the regex and the logic would still hold.

Comment: I didn’t use just PASS because it might match PASSX also

Comment: In case of PASSX, the `s` string would retain X, so although `s` would no longer represent the original data, the `split() > n` part would still behave correctly.

Comment: Good point @rowboat, made correction.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk for any characters `PASS` contains except spaces or semicolons, assuming you want `PASS` treated as a literal string rather than a regexp:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,";"); for (i in a) if (a[i] == "PASS") n--} n>1' file
ID1 PASS;mq;bq
ID4 mq;hj;cigar
ID6 bq;hj;PASS;PASS
```